# How to use python 3.5.1 with a MySQL database

Tags: python, mysql-connector

I have been trying to use MySQL in a Python project I've been working on. I downloaded the connector: `mysql-connector-python-2.1.3-py3.4-winx64` [here.](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/)

I already had Python 3.5.1 installed. When I tried to install the connector, it didn't work because it required python 2.7 instead. I have searched on many sites, even on StackOverflow I couldn't find a solution.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Try [`pymysql`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyMySQL).  It is compatible with Python 3. You can install it with pip: `pip install pymysql`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I did the steps below with Python 3.5.1 and it works:

- Download driver from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyMySQL)
- Driver installation in cmd, in this folder
  Python\Python35\PyMySQL-0.7.4\pymysql

  ```
  python setup.py build
  python setup.py install
  ```
- Copy folder Python\Python35\PyMySQL-0.7.4\pymysql to
  Python\Python35\pymysql
- Sample code in python IDE

  ```
  import pymysql
  import pymysql.cursors
  conn= pymysql.connect(host='localhost',user='user',password='user',db='testdb',charset='utf8mb4',cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
  a=conn.cursor()
  sql='CREATE TABLE `users` (`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,`email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,`password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;'
  a.execute(sql)
  ```
- Enjoy It!

Comment: just noted import "pymysql.cursors", and i am getting WinError 10061 the Mysql server:) don't we have any commands like apt get to get the whole thing including the server on windows

Comment: I did `$ pip install PyMySQL` and it worked like a charm (see [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyMySQL) )

Comment: To complete the insert remember to do a `conn.commit()`

Comment: What worked for me on Ubuntu 16 `pip3 install pymysql` and removed the line `import pymysql.cursor`.

Comment: shouldn't it be import pymysql.cursors?

Comment: @Mordechai I have imported it

Answer (score 16):

I am using **Python 3.5.2** on **window 8 pro 64-bit** and the following procedure is worked for me.

1. Download driver (PyMySQL-0.7.9.tar.gz (md5)) from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyMySQL)
2. Extract and copy the folder **pymysql** into the python Lib folder e.g (C:\Users\MyUsername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Lib)
3. Copy and run the following **example.py**

> ```
> #!/usr/bin/env python
>
> import pymysql
>
> conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', port=3306, user='root', passwd='', db='sandbox')
>
> cur = conn.cursor()
> cur.execute("SELECT * FROM users")
>
> print(cur.description)
> print()
>
> for row in cur:
>     print(row)
>
> cur.close()
> conn.close()
> ```

I hope it will work for you as well. **Happy coding :)**

Comment: This also works on Windows 10 with Python 3.6.3 and MariaDB 10.2.9.

Answer (score 4):

Try this link: [MySQL - Downloads - Connector - Python](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/)

From `Select Platform`, select the `platform independent` an **download MySQLconnector.**

After extracting the file go to its directory where **setup.py**  is located.

**WINDOWS:** press <kbd>shift</kbd> + **right_click** and open command windows and
type:

```
python setup.py install`
```

Comment: Brilliant! This worked for me on Windows with python3.5 when I couldn't find any other way to get mysql package (dependency for sqlalchemy)

Comment: I had to start the power shell as Administrator to be able to install the package to site-packages. It worked then using Python 3.6.

Answer (score 3):

Visit this web site and you will find a mysqld package that works fine with Python 3 on Windows : http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Otherwise you can use [pymysql](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyMySQL) which might be slower but works fine with Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [mysqlclient library](https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python). Install with: `pip install mysqlclient`

It is a fork of MySQLdb ( which was formerly installed via `pip install mysql-python`) that supports Python 3.*

This library talks to the MySQL client's C-interface, and is faster than the pure-python `pymysql` libray.

*Note: you will need the mysql-developer tools installed. An easy way to do this on a Mac is to run `brew install mysql` to delegate this task to **homebrew**. If you are on linux, you can install these via the instructions at the `mysqlclient` [github page](https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python).

Answer (score 1):

In `Windows`, I used:

```
pip3 install pymysql
```

Comment: This is an identical answer to one above in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing mysql database connection problem with Windows, Python 3.5.2 and Django. But finally I resolved it by installing "**mysqlclient‑1.3.9‑cp35‑cp35m‑win32.whl**" from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient

Download the whl file, then enter into same directory in command prompt and run the below command.

**pip install mysqlclient-1.3.9-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl**

*Note: Python 3.5.2 does not have official support for MySQL yet, so its just un-official binary to over come this problem for now.*

Hope that will help you !!!