# Installing MySql for python 3.5.2

Tags: python, mysql, django, pip

I was trying to installed Mysql as i started off with Django, the methods I have followed:

1)pip install MySQL-python

error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat( Does MSvisual studio needed?,I am not sure whether I have it or not maybe I got MSVS 2005)

2)https://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/( only for 2.7 no package for 3.5)

3)https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/ (registry error, it searches for 3.4..)

Can anyone help me with this, I was puzzled I am on windows 7

Comment: Python 3.5.2 on window 8 pro 64-bit well explained answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39795441/4408044)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL-python package is for 2.* version

it's been while but i think still there is no mysql connector for 3.5

your best option is to downgrade to python 3.4 and use mysql cli3ent

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

i havn't tested but [some say](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35684400/how-to-use-python-3-5-1-with-a-mysql-dtabase) this works for 3.5 but i wouldn't count on it

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyMySQL

good luck

Comment: Max i could success fully installed the mysql client now gotta deal with the server:)