# Connect python with a MySQL database

Tags: python, mysql

I have the latest version of python installed and it seems that no connection tool seems to be compatible with that version

Google searches lead to

- "mySQLdb" which seams to be outdated at this point - if I use "pip install mySQL" it throws an error (could not find a version that statisfies the requirement mySQLdb - no matching distribution found) and some searches hint that it was never developed for python 3.x until I found this blog: http://mysql-python.blogspot.de/ which hints that the command was just wrong but "pip install MySQL-python" copies only parts of the stuff until it throws the error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
- "mySQL Connector" (the api from mysql) throws an error: python 3.4 not found. I mean I don't have 3.4.0 but 3.4.3 maybe that is the reason

Tools like SQLAlchemy require you to have a connection tool already.
I mean I could also use a different database than mysql - but it seemed to be one of the common ones...

It could very well be that I completely missed one of the more recent tools. But since this is something that stopped me from getting anywhere for quite some days now I decided to ask.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37730602/1474573

Comment: thanks,  pymsql could be successfully downloaded - now I just have to figure out how to use it I guess ;-)